# How to hide Laravel paginate in search engines

Tags: php, html, laravel, seo, laravel-5

How can I hide pages render in search engines . and google just Identified for example blog, Not blog?page=5.

Can i do this with Canonical URL?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en) says you should not worry about this, this is how they index your page. Best you can do is to provide rel="prev"`and`next` links:

> If you paginate content on your site, and you want that content to
>   appear in search results, we recommend one of the following three
>   options.
>
> - Do nothing. Paginated content is very common, and Google does a good job returning the most relevant results to users, regardless of
>     whether content is divided into multiple pages.
> - Specify a View All page. Searchers commonly prefer to view a whole article or category on a single page. Therefore, if we think this is
>     what the searcher is looking for, we try to show the View All page in
>     search results. You can also add a rel="canonical" link to the
>     component pages to tell Google that the View All version is the
>     version you want to appear in search results.
> - Use rel="next" and
>     rel="prev" links to indicate the relationship between component URLs.
>     This markup provides a strong hint to Google that you would like us to
>     treat these pages as a logical sequence, thus consolidating their
>     linking properties and usually sending searchers to the first page.